# jquery scroll, change navigation active class as the page is scrolling messed up, and making wrong links active?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5Cfm6/1/

So whenever I click on watch, it goes to the div with the video, but if I click any other link on the nav bar, it sometimes highlights the active link, and it's always the wrong link. For example, if I click on about, it will highlight links. Could someone help me to get it to highlight the correct div that I'm currently at?

This is what I have so far.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('.container div').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }`enter code here`

}).scroll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point out that (at least in your fiddle) the "sponsors" `div` is **outside** of `div.container`, so it will probably not work for sponsors (e.g. if you add more sections after "sponsors") and even if it accidentaly does now, you might run into other unexpected problems in the future.

So, what you have to do for your code to (not accidentaly) work correctly is:

1. Place the "sponsors" `div` inside the `div.container`.
2. Change:
   `$('.container div').each(function (i) {` to
   `$('.container > div').each(function (i) {`
3. Change:
   `if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 20) {` to
   `if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 34) {`,
   since this is the `scrollTop` offset you set in line 4 (`scrollPoint = $('...').offset().top - 34`).

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/EY9ye/)** can be found here.

**EDIT**:
One last case you might want to address is when the last section's height is smaller than the current windows height, so that it is impossible for `scrollTop` to ever reach the last section's `position().top`. In that case, it still makes sense to hightlight the last element in nav-bar, when the user has scrolled all the way to the bottom. This can be achieved by means of this small addition:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
    var fromBottom = $(document).height() 
                     - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height());
    if (fromBottom == 0) {     // <-- scrolled to the bottom
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:last').addClass('active');
    } else if ...
```

(The **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/EY9ye/)** has been updated to illustrate that too.)

*(NOTE: Not relevant to the current question, but you might want to replace the `</br>`s in your code with `<br/>` :))*

Comment: Thank you, I just realized, that my code stopped working when I added more divs after the sponsor, thanks for pointing out that the sponser div was outside  container! solved my problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I also noticed in your second fiddle (the one you removed), you had `windscroll - 34`, when it should be `windscroll + 34`. Also, you have to change `if (windscroll >= 100) {` to `if (windscroll > 34) {`, in order for the "watch" section to be recognized properly. You can also see the working demo mentioned in my answer, which has been updated to incorporate this change. Always glad to help ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't tell you how grateful I am! Here is what I have so far :) http://www.wearanopenheart.com/test/ Thank you again!!

Comment: This looks nice so far. See my updated answer and demo for handling the existence of a last section that does not exceed the window's height.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going to make my contact form a little bit taller, but now I don't need to!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to target direct child of `.container` div instead of every descendants as well as you need to increase the value of `i` by 1 since it's 0-based:

```
$('.container > div').each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) {
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a').eq(index).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cfm6/3/)**